# Was solving a hacker problem and some test cases didnt pass

Tags: python-3.x

Given the names and grades for each student in a Physics class of  students, store them in a nested list and print the name(s) of any student(s) having the second lowest grade.

Note: If there are multiple students with the same grade, order their names alphabetically and print each name on a new line.

Input Format

The first line contains an integer, , the number of students. 
The  subsequent lines describe each student over  lines; the first line contains a student's name, and the second line contains their grade.

Constraints

There will always be one or more students having the second lowest grade.
Output Format

Print the name(s) of any student(s) having the second lowest grade in Physics; if there are multiple students, order their names alphabetically and print each one on a new line.

This is my code:

```
list = []
for _ in range(int(input())):
    name = input()
    score = float(input())
    new = [name, score]
    list.append(new)

def snd_highest(val):
    return val[1]
list.sort(key = snd_highest)
list.sort()
value = list[1]
grade = value[1]
for a,b in list:
    if b == grade:
        print (a)
```

This is the test case:
4
Rachel
-50
Mawer
-50
Sheen
-50
Shaheen
51

And the expected output is Shaheen but i got the other 3.
Please explain.

Answer (score 0):

To find the second lowest value, you have actually just sorted your list in ascending order and just taken the second value in the list by using the below code

```
value = list[1]
grade = value[1]
```

Imagine this is your list after sorting:

```
[['Sheen', 50.0], ['mawer', 50.0], ['rachel', 50.0], ['shaheen', 51.0]]
```

According to `value = list[1]`, the program chooses "value = ['mawer', 50.0]".

Then the rest of your program takes the grade from this value and outputs the corresponding name, that's why this isn't working as per what you need, you need to write logic to find the lowest value and then find the second lowest, this current program just assumes the lowest value is in the second position in the list.

Comment: oh thnx.It helped.

Comment: but th thing is inputs are all negative except the grade of shaheen ,so the second highest should be other 3s isnt it?

Comment: Even if they are negative 50, they will be sorted in the same way in ascending order and then since u are directly taking value = list[1], the algorithm wont work out. You cannot always except the second highest to be exactly at that position.

Comment: if my answer helped you, please do give an upvote or make it the accepted answer, it would help a lot.

Comment: sorry bro i gave an upvote but its not showing cuz i have no minimum reputation.

Comment: Thats fine, thanks a lot for the upvote. Even if it doesnt show it will affect my rep. Do keep the upvote. Thankyou.

Answer (score -1):

### Try doing this

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
        students = []
        for _ in range(int(input())):
            name = input()
            score = float(input())
            new = [name, score]
            students.append(new)


def removeMinimum(oldlist):
 oldlist = sorted(oldlist, key=lambda x: x[1])
 min_ = min(students, key=lambda x: x[1])
 newlist = []

 for a in range(0, len(oldlist)):
     if min_[1] != oldlist[a][1]:
        newlist.append(oldlist[a])

 return newlist

students = removeMinimum(students);
# find the second minimum value 
min_ = min(students, key=lambda x: x[1])
# sort alphabetic order 
students = sorted(students, key=lambda x: x[0])
for a in range(0, len(students)):
     if min_[1] == students[a][1]:
      print(students[a][0])
```

Answer (score -1):

I hope this may help you to pass all your test cases. Thank you.

```
# These functions will be used for sorting
def getSecond(ele):
    return ele[1]
def getFirst(ele):
    return ele[0]

studendList = []
sortedList = []
secondLowestStudents = []

# Reading input from STDIN and saving in nested list [["stud1": <score>], ["stud2", <score>]]
for _ in range(int(input())):
    name = input()
    score = float(input())
    studendList.append([name, score])

# sort the list by score and save it in a new list studendList (remove the duplicate score as well - see, if x[1] not in sortedList)
studendList.sort(key=getSecond)
[sortedList.append(x[1]) for x in studendList if x[1] not in sortedList]

# Get the second lowest grade
secondLowest = sortedList[1]

# Now sort the origin list by the name fetch the student list having the secondLowest grade
studendList.sort(key=getFirst)
[secondLowestStudents.append(x[0]) for x in studendList if x[1] == secondLowest]

# Print the student's name having second-lowest grade
for st in secondLowestStudents:
    print(st)
```